# Error thrown in update-alternatives

Tags: java, linux

I am trying to install jdk for 32-bit OS. Followed the below steps,

1. `wget --no-cookies --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u38-b05/jdk-6u38-linux-i586.bin`
2. `chmod u+x jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin`
3. `./jdk-6u34-linux-i586.bin`
4. `mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/javac /usr/bin/javaws`
5. `mv jdk1.6.0_3.`/usr/lib/jvm/`
6. `update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java" 1`
7. `update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javac" "javac" "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/javac" 1`
8. `update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_38/bin/javaws" 1`

but while running cmd 6 i am getting below error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/java because link group java is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/java with a link.
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_38/bin/javac because link group javac is broken.
update-alternatives: warning: not replacing /usr/bin/javac with a link.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_38/bin/javaws doesn't exist.
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

if you need to install java in Ubuntu, you can try using following command and you will get oracle-java-installer in your synaptic package manager, click it and install it.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
```

Else try following steps

```
 $ wget http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u34-b04/jre-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ chmod u+x jre-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ ./jre-6u34-linux-i586.bin
 $ sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm
 $ sudo mv jre1.6.0_34 /usr/lib/jvm/
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/java" "java" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_34/bin/java" 1
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/libjavaplugin.so" "mozilla-javaplugin.so" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_34/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so" 1
 $ sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/javaws" "javaws" "/usr/lib/jvm/jre1.6.0_34/bin/javaws" 1
```

Comment: While trying cmd1 'sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java' i get below error 
"sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found"
       - While trying cmd 2 - tats wat i have posted..

Comment: I fixed the error by cmd "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install python-software-properties"

Comment: i tried your first solution.. thanks a lot for that additional information. have selected yours as best solution..

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that you have created a folder named "java" in /usr/bin . Remove the folder from /usr/bin and run the command again.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of Step 4 :
4. `mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm /usr/bin/java /usr/bin/javac /usr/bin/javaws`

Just use

`$mkdir -p /usr/lib/jvm`

and make sure that you are moving the files to usr/lib/jvm , for that use

`$mv -v jre1.6.0_34 /usr/lib/jvm/`

so that you can see the details and after installation change the configuration of java and javaws by :

`$update-alternatives --config java`

select from the option
similarly ,

`$update-alternatives --config javaws`

this should work if you have already another java installed

Answer (score 1):

Remove folder **java** from **/usr/bin** and try again